# Ant Non Recursive Fileset

Tags: ant, jenkins

Here is my directory structure:

```
module/
    a/
        foo.php
        b/
            bar.php
    b/
    c/
```

I would like to run a command for each directory under module/ but non recursively, so only these should be included:

```
a/
b/
c/
```

If I do this:

```
<target name="foo">
    <apply executable="ls">
        <arg value="-l" />
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/module/">
        </fileset>
    </apply>
</target>
```

This will run recursively for each directory and file under module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only want to do this in the first level of directories?

```
<target name="foo">
    <apply executable="ls">
        <arg value="-l" />
        <dirset dir="${basedir}/module/">
            <include name="*"/>
        </dirset>
    </apply>
</target>
```

Note the `<include>`. I'm specifying only the directories immediately under the directory I specified in my `<dirset/>`. If I said, `<include names="**/*"/>`, it would specify all directories.

When you are dealing with directories and not files, use `<dirset/>` and not `<fileset/>`. `<fileset/>` is for specifying files. `<dirset/>` is for specifying directories.